# Plot to highlight selected data

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, handles

I'd like to create something similar to [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/creating_guis/gui-that-displays-and-graphs-tabular-data.html).  The differences are: my table only has one column, which is the variable I changed to get my data.  I have the table set up and working, and most of what I have works, but I only seem to be able to highlight one thing at once.  This is what I have:

```
% Set up plots etc

for a = 1:length(data);
    xAxis = data{a,1}(:,X);
    yAxis = data{a,1}(:,Y);
    plot(graph,xAxis,yAxis);
% Visible data
    hilite = plot(graph,xAxis,yAxis,'o-','LineWidth',2,'HandleVisibility','off','Visible','off');
% Invisible data, to be highlighted later
    hold all
end
hold off

% Data table callback function
function dataTable_Callback(hObject, eventdata)
    set(hilite,'Visible','off')
    names = get(hObject,'Data');
    select = eventdata.Indices(:,1);
    for d = 1:length(select)
        group = select(d);
        xAxis = []; 
        % makes sure that previously selected data is removed
        yAxis = [];
        xAxis(:,d) = data{group,1}(:,X);
        % if I remove the semicolon and let MATLAB print this data, I always get 
        the correct data in the correct columns, adding and subtracting them when 
        I select them
        yAxis(:,d) = data{group,1}(:,Y);
        set(hilite,'Visible','on','XData',xAxis(:,d),'YData',yAxis(:,d))
        legend(hilite, num2str(names{select,1}(1,1)));
    end
end
```

I've been playing with this for a few hours now, and I really can't work out what my issue is.  Any help is obviously much appreciated! :-)